# any of the other instruments / any other instrument

Tags: sentence-construction

> 1.I can play guitar, but I can't play any of the other instruments present in the world. Guitar is the only instrument that I can play.
>
> 2.I can play guitar, but I can't play any other instrument present in the world. Guitar is the only instrument that I can play.
>
> a. If I start to date a girl, I stop keeping in touch with any of the other girls that I know. My girlfriend is the only person that I keep in touch with.
>
> b. If I start to date a girl, I stop keeping in touch with any other girl that I know. My girlfriend is the only person that I keep in touch with.

For me, 1. 2. are familiar but I've seen many people use 2. and 4. I'd like to know which one is preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the first form if I'm talking about the fact that guitar is the only one *in a specific subset* of instruments that I can't play, e.g.,

> I can play guitar, but I can't play any of the other instruments that rock stars usually use.

I would use the second form if I'm talking about *all* other instruments:

> I can play guitar, but I can't play any other instrument.

Comment: how about this sentence? I can play guitar, but I can't play any of the other instruments in the room. Guitar is the only instrument that I can play. I think it's only when I'm mentioning a definite or specific instruments that I can use "any of the instruments  ~". Am I right?

Comment: @jihoon, right, "any of the" makes sense when you're talking about a specific set or group, rather than ALL others in the world.